# PyQt5.4.1 failing to install with python 3.4 on Mac OS X 10.10.2

Tags: python, macos

I am having a problem installing PyQt5.4.1 with Python 3.4 on Mac OS X 10.10.2.  I have followed [these suggestions](https://gist.github.com/vityafx/e01ab56d28a2c9467cc6), but the following occurs:

```
    Nates-iMac:PyQt-gpl-5.4.1 Nate$ python configure.py --destdir /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    Determining the details of your Qt installation...
    This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.4.1 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.4.2 on darwin.

    Type 'L' to view the license.
    Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
    Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

    Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
    Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
    Error: Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument to explicitly specify a working sip.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install sip with `"make install"` you should see a line like

```
cp -f sip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
```

When you configure PyQt with `"python configure.py"` add the --sip argument with something like the path `cp -f sip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip`

I had the same problem as described in your post, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing:

```
python3 configure.py -q /Users/Lexynux/Qt5.4.2/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

Because that's the version of python you have installed, or not? So you must execute the correct version of python.

PD.
Do not forget to change the username 'Lexynux' for yours!